# How to use aws ec2 create-tags (from aws cli) to give different values to the same tag across multiple resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Suppose I have a list of instance ids and I want to change the tag "Name" to a certain value in all of those instances. I can run

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources i-0ba60d097b9a4aebc i-051a64ccc686602e3 i-09c6265c16961a7a0 --tags Key=Name,Value=newname
```

and the value of the tag `Name` will change to `newname` in the three instances I specified. Is there a way to give a separate value to the tag `Name` for each of the three instances? That is `newname1`, `newname2` and `newname3` to the three respective instances.

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources i-0ba60d097b9a4aebc --tags Key=Name,Value=newname1 --resources i-051a64ccc686602e3 --tags Key=Name,Value=newname2 --resources i-09c6265c16961a7a0 --tags Key=Name,Value=newname3
```

is not the correct syntax. I don't want to call `aws ec2 create-tags` separately for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

No. You would need to run separate `aws ec2 create-tags` commands to apply different tags to different instances:

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources i-0ba60d097b9a4aebc --tags Key=Name,Value=newname1 
aws ec2 create-tags --resources i-051a64ccc686602e3 --tags Key=Name,Value=newname2 
aws ec2 create-tags --resources i-09c6265c16961a7a0 --tags Key=Name,Value=newname3
```

Comment: Okay. But I wanted to avoid making multiple calls of ```aws ec2 create-tags``` and was trying to see if it could be achieved in a single call.

Comment: No, that is not possible.